# Error joining strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to join all strings contained in an array in one single string so I've come up with this code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *join_strings(const char *array[])
{
    int n_array (sizeof (array) / sizeof (const char *));

    int i;
    int total_length;
    char *joined;
    char *end;
    int *lengths;

    lengths = (int *)malloc (n_array * sizeof (int));
    if (!lengths) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    total_length = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n_array; i++) {
        lengths[i] = strlen (array[i]);
        total_length += lengths[i];
    }

    joined = (char *)malloc(total_length + 1);

    if (!joined) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    end = joined;

    for (i = 0; i < n_array; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < lengths[i]; j++) {
            end[j] = array[i][j];
        }
        end += lengths[i];
    }
    end[total_length] = '\0';

    char *result = joined;

    free (lengths);
    free (joined);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const char *lol0 = "First";
    const char *lol1 = "Second";
    const char *fullString[] = { lol0, lol1 };
    const char *joined = join_strings(fullString);

    puts(joined);

    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason it only output "First", don't know the problem might be. :/
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen the [`strcat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) function?  (Specifically, use `strlcat` or `strncat` if they're available, in that order.)

Comment: This code is C++, not C. `int n_array (sizeof (array) / sizeof (const char *));` seems invalid in C and gcc emits compile error for it.

Comment: If you are trying to write C++, you should use `new []` instead of `malloc`, but prefer `std::string` and container classes over `new`.

Comment: There are so many other questions about array to pointer decay I can't even choose a duplicate. In general though, you aren't passing an array in any useful sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(array)` equals to `sizeof(const char **)` and `n_array` isn't accurately calculated.
You will have to pass the length of array as an argument.

There is another error. You must not do `free (joined);` in function `join_strings` since the buffer is still used.

Fixed code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *join_strings(const char *array[], int n_array)
{

    int i;
    int total_length;
    char *joined;
    char *end;
    int *lengths;

    lengths = malloc (n_array * sizeof (int));
    if (!lengths) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    total_length = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n_array; i++) {
        lengths[i] = strlen (array[i]);
        total_length += lengths[i];
    }

    joined = malloc(total_length + 1);

    if (!joined) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    end = joined;

    for (i = 0; i < n_array; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < lengths[i]; j++) {
            end[j] = array[i][j];
        }
        end += lengths[i];
    }
    end[total_length] = '\0';

    char *result = joined;

    free (lengths);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const char *lol0 = "First";
    const char *lol1 = "Second";
    const char *fullString[] = { lol0, lol1 };
    char *joined = join_strings(fullString, 2);

    puts(joined);
    free(joined);

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- This code is C, not C++. I removed casts for the return value of `malloc`, which seems to be hated in this site. This will lead to compile error in C++.
- to `free` the buffer, the type of `joined` in the `main` function shouldn't be `const char*`. gcc made warnings for it.

Comment: "I removed casts for the return value of malloc, which seems to be hated in this site." might be worth linking to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be absolutely sure, but it's possible that performance-wise the win from knowing the lengths is less than the cost of allocating heap memory just to hold string lengths.

So, let's do it without that extra length-buffering, for fun:

```
char * join_strings(const char *array, size_t array_len)
{
  size_t out_len;

  for(size_t i = out_len = 0; i < array_len; ++i)
    out_len += strlen(array[i]);

  char *out = malloc(out_len + 1);
  if(out != NULL)
  {
    char *put = out;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < array_len; ++i)
    {
      for(const char *src = array[i]; *src;)
        *put++ = *src++;
    }
    *put = '\0';
  }
  return out;
}
```

The above is C99, by the way. I removed the error message, returning `NULL` might be enough. It's not tested, but shouldn't be too far from correct. :)

My point is basically that sometimes shorter code is easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by MikeCAT, the following does not do what you think it is doing... but Why?

> ```
> char *join_strings(const char *array[])
> {
>     int n_array (sizeof (array) / sizeof (const char *));
> ```

You are passing `*fullString[]` to your `join_strings` function, but what `join_strings` gets is effectively `**fulString` due to pointer decay. Any time you pass an array to a function (e.g. `a[]`) it will decay to a pointer (e.g. `*a`). The same is true for an array of pointers.

That is precisely the reason you see the `main` function syntax as:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

or

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

In fact, what main receives is the second case, but the syntax allowed is either. So when you pass `*fullString[]` to your `join_strings` function, pointer decay insures that `join_strings` receives `**fullString`. That makes the following:

> ```
>     int n_array (sizeof (array) / sizeof (const char *));
> ```

effectively `int n_array 8/8` or `1`. The `sizeof array / sizeof *array` only works in the scope where `array` is declared and defined. Once you pass it to another function, pointer decay renders it incorrect.

However, your code is not far off otherwise. There were a few changes to make, but other than this bit of learning that was needed, you were close to a working string concatenation:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *join_strings (const char **array, size_t n_array)
{
    // int n_array (sizeof (array) / sizeof (const char *));

    size_t i;
    size_t total_length;
    char *joined;
    char *end;
    size_t *lengths;

    // lengths = (int *) malloc (n_array * sizeof (int));
    lengths = malloc (n_array * sizeof *lengths);
    if (!lengths) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    total_length = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n_array; i++) {
        lengths[i] = strlen (array[i]);
        total_length += lengths[i];
    }

    joined = malloc (total_length + 1);

    if (!joined) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    end = joined;

    for (i = 0; i < n_array; i++) {
        size_t j;
        for (j = 0; j < lengths[i]; j++) {
            end[j] = array[i][j];
        }
        end += lengths[i];
    }
    // end[total_length] = '\0';   /* ALWAYS run valgrind (Note3) */
    joined[total_length] = '\0';

    // char *result = joined;

    free (lengths);
    // free (joined);

    return joined;
}

int main ()
{
    const char *lol0 = "First";
    const char *lol1 = "Second";
    const char *fullString[] = { lol0, lol1 };
/*const */char *joined = join_strings (fullString, sizeof fullString/sizeof *fullString);

    puts (joined);
    free (joined);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note** the change from `int` to `size_t` in your function for all your length and counter variables. You need to try and match your types to the actual ranges of numbers they will hold. Since there is no negative-length and you are only using positive counters to count up, `size_t` will help the compiler warn you when you might be trying to use the variables incorrectly.

**Note2:** don't cast the return on `malloc`. It is nothing more than the address to the start of a memory block. It doesn't have a type. Casting `malloc` provides *zero* benefit, but can mask errors or warnings the compiler would otherwise generate to warn you when you are about to do something dumb.

**Note3:** If you are allocating memory dynamically **Always** run your code through valgrind to insure you are using the memory properly. There is no excuse not to, it is dead-bang easy:

```
valgrind ./myprogname
```

It not only checks your allocations and frees, but it also check whether you attempt to access memory outside your allocated blocks. (if you compile with symbols enabled `-g` valgrind will show you the line numbers associated with the errors) Here valgrind shows:

```
==27700== Invalid write of size 1
==27700==    at 0x40090E: join_strings (ptrdecay.c:45)
==27700==    by 0x400960: main (ptrdecay.c:60)
==27700==  Address 0x51e00a6 is 10 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==27700==    at 0x4C29964: calloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27700==    by 0x400838: join_strings (ptrdecay.c:29)
==27700==    by 0x400960: main (ptrdecay.c:60)
```

Huh? Look closely at how your were attempting to null-terminate `end`. What is the value of `end` at that time? Where does `end[total_length]` (or equivalently written `*(end + total_length)` ) put that null-terminator?

```
==27700==  Address 0x51e00a6 is 10 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
```

There is one other warning you should fix, either by using `calloc` for `joined` or initializing its values to `0` before filling them. That is all valgrind is complaining about in:

```
==27647== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==27647==    at 0x4C2ACF8: strlen (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27647==    by 0x4E9DE2B: puts (in /lib64/libc-2.18.so)
==27647==    by 0x40092B: main (ptrdecay.c:62)
```

The easiest way to eliminate this message is with:

```
    joined = calloc (1, total_length + 1);
```

Try it and see... When you fix all the issues and run valgrind again, you will see what you want to see everytime:

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ptrdecay
==27821== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27821== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27821== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27821== Command: ./bin/ptrdecay
==27821==
FirstSecond
==27821==
==27821== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27821==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27821==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 28 bytes allocated
==27821==
==27821== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==27821==
==27821== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27821== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this code is horrible - all this manual `malloc` and bare `const char *` arrays are very poor style.

Secondly, you're just passing the address of the first array element. Despite the misleading `[]`, both C and C++ decay the argument to a pointer in this case, and the array size information is lost.

However, if your array size is genuinely a compile-time constant rather than being dynamically allocated, it *is* possible to make this work without changing your effective interface:

```
template <size_t n_array>
char *join_strings(const char *(&array)[n_array])
{
    // other ghastly code omitted for aesthetic reasons
}
```

will be callable exactly as shown and (once you fix the double free bug) actually work.

A minimal solution in actual C++ would instead be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

template <typename InputIterator>
std::string join_strings(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(os));
    return os.str();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> arr = {"First","Second"};
    std::string joined = join_strings(begin(arr), end(arr));
    std::cout << joined << '\n';
}
```

This *will* have some redundant allocations, but is actually correct, and just as importantly is vastly simpler. If you profile and genuinely need more speed, replace the `ostringstream` with a pre-sized `std::string` and `append` to it.

Comment: I'm not sure that would get around the `free (joined);` further down in the function, but with those two changes, then yes, you would get output, but work?

Comment: Oh yeah, I skipped over the bugs not directly related to the question, to avoid thinking about the rest of the code.

Comment: The remainder turned into more of a game of *whack-a-mole* `:)`